# how to decrypt the HMACSHA512 passwords

Tags: c#

I am encrypting(hashing) user login passwords using HMACSHA512 using (PasswordToHash(_salt, passwordText, iterations)) and stored in database. I would like to know how to decrypt the passwords.

Comment: You can't decrypt hashes, and that's what HMACSHA512 is: **a hasher**.

Comment: The point of a hash algorithm is that it is one-way, therefore you can't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you cannot decrypt one way hashes

Answer (score 2):

You do not decrypt hashes, you recreate the hashes from user input and compare with the stored value.

Comment: every time it will create different hashes for same password.how to compare?

Comment: @SureshSankar then you are doing something wrong.  A hash should always return the same output for the same input.

Comment: With the same password, salt, and iterations, you will get the same hash.  If you generate a new salt each time you verify, then, of course, it won't work.   That is why you store the salt and the hash in your database.

Comment: following the below link https://github.com/Thashiznets/PWDTK.NET for hashing the password.
In that sample create different hashes for same password

Comment: thanks for ur commands.

Comment: In that link, a new salt and hash is created every time a new password is entered (button1_Click), but the current salt&hash are used to verify (button2_click).